# How to output a stdout both to a process and the shell screen

Tags: bash, stdout, tee

Do someone knows a way to send the stdout of a command both to another command and display it in the shell screen? Note: without using files.

An example (in this case I use wc -l to make it simple )

```
~> echo "test" | wc -l
1
```

but I need to have

```
test
1
```

I have tried the tee command, expecting it would do it, but it returns the same thing

```
~> echo "test" | tee | wc -l
1
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really clear how you want the output to be formatted. Even, if you use `tee` the output will be redirected to `wc -l`. So, you will not see the output of `echo`.

I can think of a workaround to send both of `echo` output and `wc -l` to the terminal by sending one to `stdout` and `stderr` using:

```
$ echo "test" | tee /dev/stderr | wc -l
test
1
```

This way you will both sent to your terminal via `stdout` and `stderr`.

The idea of using named pipes posted by @DukeLion is a nice one also.

Answer (score 2):

You can use named pipe with tee to do the trick.

create named pipe:  `mkfifo /tmp/testpipe`

use tee to duplicate output to stdout and pipe: `echo "test" | tee /tmp/testpipe`

Your command will hang at this moment, since nothing is connected to pipe output. You need to run in different shell `cat /tmp/testpipe | wc -l`

Named pipe is a file, but it will not do neither disk io nor memory buffering.

Comment: Thanks @DukeLion, and I have tested it works. You make me discover the named pipes, I will use it in other situations as in this case I must run this into bash script.

Comment: No problem, just run `echo "test" | tee /tmp/testpipe` in background, like this `echo "test" | tee /tmp/testpipe &`

Comment: Thanks @DukeLion! 
For those who just need to duplicate stdout for multiple processes, the `cat` will exit upon end of the first piped output. Therefore, one may wish to put `cat` into a while loop: 
`while true ; do cat /tmp/testpipe ; done &`